# Cleaned up tags reappearing?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki, clean-up

A few months ago, as part of the great tag clean up, my beloved [japanese](/questions/tagged/japanese) tag was removed.

Recently, it's reappeared:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/japanese

So two questions spring to mind:

1. Should we allow tags that have been deliberately removed as part of a clean up to be re-added? At the moment, if it stays, we're saying that there wasn't any point in removing it the first time...
2. If the tag is back, is it acceptable that we've lost all the tag wiki information? In this case, I'd spent time on the old wiki page, linking to common questions and providing an overview etc. Granted, I didn't spend too long on it, but I don't like the idea of my work being wiped arbitrarily.

---

Is a possible solution to make all language tags a synonym for [internationalization](/questions/tagged/internationalization) or similar?

Comment: Oh, FFS.  Why is this back!?!?!?  \*pulls hair out\*

Comment: @casperOne Well, that's a more succinct way of putting my question. :)

Comment: I've removed the tag, but your questions are still valid (as this is a generalized question regarding any tag).

Comment: Technically all the wiki info isn't lost, it goes into orphan-wiki mode (mods can access a list of orphaned tag wikis).

Comment: Side question: if the `japanese` tag isn't allowed, does that mean the [`turkish`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/turkish) and [`polish`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polish) tags are not as well?

Comment: @Manishearth Hmm, but you'd think there'd be a mechanism to re-associate the orphaned wiki with the tag if it reappears?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I don't think many people would be happy with an 'okay for some' (languages) scenario. The policy should apply to all (non-programming) languages the same way.

Comment: @Mikaveli: true.

Comment: I believe that people believed it was a valid tag, but honestly, it's as useless as `string`; the tag requires further context to be useful.  The usage of `japanese` will vary across the problem requirements.  It's more a matter of getting the right category to group these problems, whether they be related to Unicode rendering, RTL languages, etc.

Comment: You do get a few questions that are quite language specific though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249409/in-html-and-css-how-do-i-make-japanese-text-break-lines-correctly/5535938 Admittedly, often the questions could relate to any non-Latin character support question though.

Comment: @casperOne - [it's baaaaaaaaaaaack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631168/validate-japanese-character-in-active-record-callback) (yes, I could edit it out, but it's more fun to point out zombie tags)

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers BLAH!  Let's hope it doesn't come back after the change I just made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly believe that greater use of blacklisting is required.

There are some tags, [collaboration](/questions/tagged/collaboration) or [game](/questions/tagged/game), for instance, that are just useless, and yet will always be used again (and again and again). They only become useful if a language / tool / module / etc appears with that name.

I understand that blacklisting is currently frowned upon; but, it needn't be. If blacklisting were made a mod power then adding tags to the blacklist would be easier than it is currently. More importantly removing them, when required, becomes a lot easier as well.

The *only* use these tags have is to help with the tracking down of off-topic / just bad questions. Even then, a lot of these tags aren't even useful for that.

Tags created today that *haven't yet been removed* include:

- [extension](/questions/tagged/extension)
- [computer](/questions/tagged/computer)
- [temporary-variables](/questions/tagged/temporary-variables)
- [rendered](/questions/tagged/rendered)
- [net](/questions/tagged/net)
- [tides](/questions/tagged/tides)
- [participant](/questions/tagged/participant)
- [pin-code](/questions/tagged/pin-code)

Most of these are pointless; let's blacklist the really bad ones, [computer](/questions/tagged/computer) for example.

In the case of [japanese](/questions/tagged/japanese) I would argue for an improvement to the synonym system, which is also needed as a large proportion of synonyms require mod intervention on meta (on Stack Overflow). I've seen plenty of suggestions but none that would, I think, work. As I don't have any ideas that are better than the suggestions this section is a little bit smaller.

Comment: Not only is it frowned upon, mods can't access it (only devs and one comm team member, IIRC). So a slowish process. Not really, but the more hoops you have to jump through, the more reluctant you feel :)